# How to fix checkmarx error "... untrusted data is embedded straight into the output ..."

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkmarx

In a frontend app that uses jQuery I have an oversimplified code like this (line numbers included):

```
...
129: var buttonId = $('some-element').closest('...').siblings('...').attr('id');
130: $('#' + buttonId).focus();
...
```

And in checkmarx I get this error:

*The application's {method_name} embeds untrusted data in the generated output with $, at line 130 of {file_name}. This untrusted data is embedded straight into the output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker to inject malicious code into the output.*

So - what should I do here? ... Cause this ID attribute is just an ID, you know ... so I have no idea what sanitization or encoding I should perform on it.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar issue.

Try replace:

```js
$('#' + buttonId).focus();
```

With:

```js
jQuery('#' + buttonId).focus();
```

Somehow for this scenario the scanner doesn't know that the variable `$` is same as `jQuery` variable.

Try it out ;o)

Comment: Hm, this could have fixed it probably ... but we wrote to them, we had a discussion and they agreed to mark that as `not exploit` or something like that ... :) ... so this is long gone ... but still - thanks for the answer :)